# I want to select columns from multiple stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I want to select columns running multiple stored procedure in 'From ' as shown below.

```
select col1-sp1, col1-sp2, col1-sp3
from sp1, sp2, sp3 (list of stored procedure)
where .....
```

How can I do this?

I appreciate you reply.

Comment: Things like stored procedures (and procedural code in general) are **highly vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **concrete database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: I do not think that stored procedures can be used in sql select queries. If your stored procedure saves data in any table, then use those table names